# how can I have many web pages on a single web page?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser

I use several pages once a day and so I would like to stitch them or put them together under one "roof" as such. I thought that have them all one one web page would be perfect. But how do I go about doing this? For example, I would like a single web page (tab in my browser) that contains the feeds/or pages from Google Analytics, Klout Dashboard, Scoop.it etc.

Comment: Have you considered making our own page and embedding all those things as [iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)?

Comment: Yes, considered and rejected, I was looking for a built in or app-install tool. Really wanted a solution for Chrome as opposed to Firefox.

Comment: It's not exactly what you are asking for, but I think our product could be useful for what you want. It's a screensaver that displays web pages in rotation: https://Screensaver.Ninja.

Comment: That's great, not quite what I was looking for but still really good to have, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Firefox add-on Super Start. It allows you to add links to any number of websites on one page.

Answer (score 2):

you can use greasemonkey to piece different webpages together in firefox. there may be similar plugins/addons for chrome or other browsers though.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an answer to the suggestion of iframes within the comments of the post by @Kush.

You *may* be able to do this with HTML for some sites.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="200" height="200" scrolling="yes"></iframe> 
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp" width="200" height="200" scrolling="yes"></iframe> 

</body>
</html>
```

Copy the code above, paste into a text file, save it as MyPage.html and run it!

You will have issues though, such as you will have to log in first (I suspect) in some situations...

Sadly, [some sites prevent the browser from displaying iFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe) that are not hosted on the same domain as the parent page. As you can see, the w3school does work, the Google link does not.